# Does "parody" imply a mocking or satirical intent?

Tags: meaning

> When garnishing my cake, I attempted to parody your style of blending the glaze and frosting together with melted butter.

Is this a correct usage of the word parody given that there is no mocking or satirical intent?

Comment: *Does “parody” imply a mocking or satirical intent?* -- look up the word in a good dictionary. If you did not mean to imply what *parody* means, then why use the word? What exactly are you trying to imply instead? Please expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [standard definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parody) of parody all seem to imply some degree of mockery or satire. Certainly in your example, I would assume that you exaggerated the effect rather than simply copied it. It would probably be better to stick to "imitate", e.g.

> When garnishing my cake, I attempted to imitate your style of blending the glaze and frosting together with melted butter.